# Does my game progress get saved if I am offline?

Tags: epic-games-launcher, far-cry-6

If I play Far Cry 6 in Epic Games offline mode, will my progress be saved?

Or do I need to be connected to the internet in order to save my progress?

Answer (score 1):

If you play offline your progress will be saved only on your PC, I don't see any reason to worry about it.
What you are missing playing offline is the cloud save feature.